# YouTube not working via SSH tunnel proxy to a U.S.-based IP address

Tags: firefox, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

YouTube is blocked in my country. To connect to this site, I created a SOCKS5 SSH Tunnel proxy using this command and configured Firefox accordingly; `111.222.333.444` is a U.S.-based IP address:

```
ssh -D localproxy:9999 -C tempo@111.222.333.444
```

It connects and works well. I can Google “My IP” and I get `111.222.333.444` which means connection is working.

But still, no luck with YouTube. It won’t connect to it despite the proxy to a U.S.-based IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know some countries manipulate with DNS table. By default Firefox uses regular DNS - not the proxy one. Go to `about:config` and set `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns = true`.

Comment: It worked for me after restarting firefox. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have used an SSH tunnel before, but now I use http://proxmate.dave.cx/

You can install the extension and then install the youtube plugin and it will automatically proxy while watching youtube but all other traffic will be direct.

This is easier for me, but may not be what you want.